# Share Computer internet connection with my Google Nexus One

Tags: usb, nexus-one, internet, reverse-tether

I want to Share Computer internet connection with my Google Nexus One using usb cable. how can i do this ?

Comment: Click on the 'reverse-tether' tag I just added, and take a look at the list of questions displayed. That should give you an idea -- e.g. that it requires you to have your device rooted...